# Python printing list element

Tags: python

I noticed that in the following snippet both approaches give the same result:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> print(a[0])
1
>>> print(a)[0]
1
>>>
```

I was a bit surprised, as I would have expected `print(a)` to return a string, so then subscript 0 to just return the first character (Ie: [). However, it seems Python interprets it as a list?

Anybody able to clarify please?

Comment: In Python3, I see `print(a)[0]` giving `TypeError: NoneType is not subscriptable`.

Comment: You're using Python 2.x, so the parentheses are redundant in both cases (`print` is a *statement*, not a function) - it's always `print a[0]`. `(a[0]) is (a)[0] is a[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, you're using python 2.x, where `print` is a statement, not a function — so `print(a)[0]` being parsed as `print a[0]` — treating braces as parsing priority modifier.

Important thing — `print` does *not* return what you're printing. It sends data to stream (`stdout` by default). If you're using python 3.x (where `print` is a function) or use `from __future__ import print_function` — functions will send data to stream and return `None` as result. So `print(a)[0]` will resolve to "send content of `a` to stdout and return `None[0]`", later will raise `IndexError`

Comment: `s/probably/definitely/` - as @jpp pointed out, the second snippet would be a `TypeError` (*not* an `IndexError` as you state) in Python 3.

Comment: Edited. Normally, I don't write about my assumptions as if it reality — maybe that's some exotic version of python built from scratch ;)

Answer (score 1):

As **@jonrsharpe** mentioned in the comment block, you're probably running python 2.x.

`print` statement was replaced in python 3.x with `print()` function

```
>>> print(a)[0]
[1, 2, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```